# Wordpress get_post_meta not showing all meta from DB?

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata

On a Wordpress site, in PHP I want to read a meta-data value:
 `get_post_meta($post->ID)` to get all the post meta-data

This returns all meta data ***except for 1 entry***

```
"classic-editor-remember": "classic-editor"
"_edit_lock":              "1573652321:1"
"_edit_last":              "1"
"djs_custom_field":        "MY_CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE"

MISSING 'wp_jv_post_rg'??
```

It's a meta-data entry from a plugin called "WP JV Post Reading Groups".

The Wordpress Database *does* have this meta-data entry:  ***wp_jv_post_rg***

```
ID    POST_ID META_KEY                VALUE
1637  458     wp_jv_post_rg           a:2:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:1;}
1634  458     djs_custom_field        MY_CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE
1633  458     _edit_last              1
1632  458     _edit_lock              1573657373:1
1631  458     classic-editor-remember classic-editor
```

**Wordpress** 5.3

**Plugin**: WP JV Post Reading Groups

**Also tested**: using `get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wp_jv_post_rg',true);` (same result)

Why is this `wp_jv_post_rg` entry from the post meta-data not shown?

---

**UPDATE**:

Tested with blank WP 5.3 installation (PHP 7.2) and "JV Post Reading Groups": same result. The wp_jv_post_rg meta data is not returned with `get_post_meta`. Code:

```
// action triggered by a post publish
add_action('transition_post_status', 'send_new_post', 10, 3); 

// function to get the metadata
function send_new_post($new_status, $old_status, $post)
   $meta_values = get_post_meta($post->ID);
```

$meta_values contains:

```
 a:2:{
    s:10:"_edit_lock";
    a:1:{
       i:0;s:12:"1574332318:1";
    }
    s:10:"_edit_last";
    a:1:{
       i:0;s:1:"1";
    }
 }
```

even though the database *also* has the `wp_jv_post_rg` meta-data field.
Am I using the wrong way to read the meta-data?

**UPDATE**:

When I use `get_metadata` instead of `get_post_meta` I *do* get the required metadata, but only *after* the post has been saved. 
So it's not available (yet?) when the code gets triggered by the action

Comment: I just test the plugin "WP JV Post Reading Groups" and I don't have your problem. that may be another plugin which do that.

Comment: will test with a blank WP installation!

Comment: Tested with blank WP install: Results posted in the updated question above.